# List comprehension equivalent to map on two lists in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I understand that with one list argument `map()` can be replaced by a list comprehension. For example

```
map(lambda x : x**2, range(5))
```

can be replaced with

```
[x**2 for x in range(5)]
```

Now how would I do something similar for two parallel lists. In other words, I have a line of code with the following pattern:

```
map(func, xs, ys)
```

where `func()` takes two arguments.

How can I do the same thing with a list comprehension?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`map()` with multiple arguments is the equivalent of using the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) on those extra arguments. Use `zip()` in a list comprehension to do the same:

```
[func(x, y) for x, y in zip(xs, ys)]
```

Generally speaking, any `map(func, a1, a2, .., an)` expression can be transformed to a list comprehension with `[func(*args) for args in zip(a1, a2, .., an)]`.

Comment: This answer is less thorough than the old, popular, canonical duplicate.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: which I wasn't aware existed. Is this answer now being judged in comparison to a different question?

Comment: You didn't think there was already a question about `zip`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: no, I wasn't aware there was already a question on how to translate `map()` with multiple arguments to a list comp, no. Was I supposed to?